# Rule of thumb when working with numerous panels and JScrollPane and setPreferredSize()

Tags: java, jscrollpane

Working with a vastly complex JFrame with numerous panels within panels within panels....you get the picture. If it were simple I would post an example.

The main panel has 4 panels and each of those panels have 6 or so other panels and those may even have some panels. The main panel is placed within the JScrollPane.

The JFrame opens and as soon as the window is made smaller, the scrollbars appear which is great, but the window originally opens about 3/4 of what it should be. 
This means the window has to manually be made bigger to see it all as the scrollbars only appear if made smaller.

When dealing with so many layers of panels, what is the rule of thumb when working in this scenario. Should the setPreferredSize() be done at every panel, or just the parent panel or just the JScrollPane level or a mixture?

Answer (score -1):

I have found in this particular scenario that using setPreferredSize() on the top most panel resolved this particular issue. There are setPreferredSize() methods called on other panels and those were removed to only use the call on the top panel and this seemed to be the key.

Comment: Generally, the setPreferredSize method needs to be executed on **all** of the lowest level JPanels **that do not contain JComponents**.  If you miss one, then setting the preferred size on the main JPanel will mask the true problem.